# ViewController shows up empty in iOS Simulator swift

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, xcode-storyboard

When I run my current xcode project, with the screens shown below in image 1, it shows up empty as seen in image 2. The project was started as a single view application. I added the items shown on the screen and created a segue to the second screen based on the button press "Add".

When I run this, you can see the outcome in image 2.

The code I have in the viewDidLoad() is running and doing as expected. However, unsure of why the screens show up blank...

[image: storyboard]

[image]

Comment: For such things, I recommend you to use UINavigationController. Sure it will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things to observe before you change anything. Launch your app and change orientation to Landscape. You will have something like this.[image: App in landscape orientation]

This is because you have set your storyboard to `wCompact hCompact`.

Change it to `wAny hAny`. But before doing that remove the tabbar from `wCompact hCompact` setting. and add it after changing to `wAny hAny`

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to change your w/h to Any instead of Compact. It currently displays the view controller in a iPhone 5 simulator and Compact/Compact is for 3.5, 4, 4.7 inch in Landscape. Please refer to Apple Docs - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/SelectingASizeClass.html